# Data to Excel in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have a problem when I want to create Excel file from data that I have in vb.net.

the code are look like below.

```
  Dim Data(10, 10) As Integer
  Dim xlApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
  Dim xlBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
  Dim xlSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

  Data(0, 0) = 1
  Data(0, 1) = 2
  Data(0, 2) = 3
  Data(1, 0) = 4
  Data(1, 1) = 5
  Data(1, 2) = 6

   xlApp = GetObject("", "Excel.Application")

   xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\data excel.xls")
   xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
   xlApp.Visible = True

   xlSheet.Range(xlSheet.Cells(0, 0)).Value = Data(0, 0)
   xlSheet.Range(xlSheet.Cells(0, 1)).Value = Data(0, 1)
   xlSheet.Range(xlSheet.Cells(0, 2)).Value = Data(0, 2)
   xlSheet.Range(xlSheet.Cells(1, 0)).Value = Data(1, 0)
   xlSheet.Range(xlSheet.Cells(1, 1)).Value = Data(1, 1)
   xlSheet.Range(xlSheet.Cells(1, 2)).Value = Data(1, 2)

   xlBook.Save()
   xlBook.Close(False)
   xlApp.Quit()
```

When I run the program, I found error message "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC".

Anyone have an idea how to overcome this problem?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember Cells are 1 based so this:

```
xlSheet.Cells(1, 1) = Data(0, 0)
xlSheet.Cells(1, 2) = Data(0, 1)
...
xlSheet.Cells(2, 3) = Data(1, 2)
```

should work.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion @david. Unfortunately it doesn't work and the error is still appear.

Comment: Just checked my code and fixed the above code, this way it works for me

Comment: I've found the answer. The code is look like this --> xlSheet.Cells(1, 1) = Data(0, 0)

Comment: Just as I fixed it :) Good to hear you got it working